# when i try to compile my qt programm with makefile it doesnt work

Tags: c++, linux, qt, debian

When I compile my programm within qt everything works fine, but when I compile it manually using:

> qmake myFile.pro
>
> make

I got the following errors:

```
pat@patate:~/Desktop/alerte_red_compile$ make
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/QtNetwork -isystem /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o smtp.o smtp.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/QtNetwork -isystem /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o service.o service.cpp
service.cpp: In constructor ‘MainWindow::MainWindow()’:
service.cpp:9:5: error: ‘QMdiArea’ was not declared in this scope
     QMdiArea *zoneCentrale = new QMdiArea; //multi fenetre
     ^~~~~~~~
service.cpp:9:15: error: ‘zoneCentrale’ was not declared in this scope
     QMdiArea *zoneCentrale = new QMdiArea; //multi fenetre
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
service.cpp:9:34: error: ‘QMdiArea’ does not name a type
     QMdiArea *zoneCentrale = new QMdiArea; //multi fenetre
                                  ^~~~~~~~
service.cpp:16:5: error: ‘QGridLayout’ was not declared in this scope
     QGridLayout *boutonsLayout = new QGridLayout;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
service.cpp:16:18: error: ‘boutonsLayout’ was not declared in this scope
     QGridLayout *boutonsLayout = new QGridLayout;
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
service.cpp:16:38: error: ‘QGridLayout’ does not name a type
     QGridLayout *boutonsLayout = new QGridLayout;
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
service.cpp: In member function ‘void MainWindow::downloadFile()’:
service.cpp:140:24: error: ‘QFileDialog’ has not been declared
     QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~
Makefile:352: recipe for target 'service.o' failed
make: *** [service.o] Error 1
```

yes adding every missing library solved the problem ! but my question is why in qt creator you dont need it ? it doesnt really matter at this stage but if someone have a really clear answer that would be nice.

i guess those library are precompile in qt creator and they need to be add outside of qtcreator.

Comment: From the errors it looks like you are missing some includes for `Qt`. Do you have `#include <QMdiArea>` in service.cpp?

Comment: You probably got some headers automatically included using `qmake` that you don't have now. I would fix this by modifying your code to add the missing includes.

Comment: ok its compilling but i hope someone will have a better solution or explanation...Qt is skipping the qmake step

Comment: I say fixing the missing includes is the proper solution. In my `Qt` development I include all of the headers I need in each source file. Although I am using `CMake` to generate my projects.

Comment: You can try to compare the makefile generated by QtCreator and the one created manually. Also check the compile output window in QtCreator to compare the executed statements (f.e. the exact qmake invocation).

Comment: Qt Creator does no "magic", it uses *qmake* (*cmake* is supported too)  to generate the `Makefile`, then uses *make*. There is no difference here compared to working just from command line and/or using some other IDE or editor.

Comment: Good idea i should look at the difference in the makefile... i dont how many time i will have to repeat it but when i compile inside qtcreator i dont have to include every library, but outside i have to..qt does no magic but it is doing something for me in the background

Comment: Look at the compile commands used by Qt Creator (in Compile Output at th bottom). Compare to running from command line.

Answer (score 0):

In this cases you should first check the documentation, here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html
at the top there is a box with a line stating with "Header:".

```
Header: #include <QMdiArea>
```

It tells you which includes are needed to make it work.

The other line "qmake:"

```
qmake:  QT += widgets
```

tells you what you have to put in your .pro file. Both entries are needed to make it work (unless they are already included in some other way).

The second one tells the buildsystem, which files are needed for compilation, so it generates the compilercalls inside the makefile with the right flags. 
The first one tells the preprocessor in the compilation process which qt code parts are needed.

Remember that if you changed the .pro file, qmake has to be run again to rebuild the Makefile.